# google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.}

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In one my application files, I am running a query on BQ Public Tables.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pyarrow
client = bigquery.Client(project = "project-name")
os.environ.setdefault("GCLOUD_PROJECT", "project-name")


sql = """
  SELECT *
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.cbsa`
  WHERE name IN UNNEST(%s)
""" %(metros)

df_geom = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
```

When I run the Application, I am getting a `google.auth.exception` out of nowhere.

```
File "/Users/...tab1.py", line 72, in <module>
    df_geom = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 3391, in query
    future = do_query()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 3368, in do_query
    query_job._begin(retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 1249, in _begin
    super(QueryJob, self)._begin(client=client, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 509, in _begin
    api_response = client._call_api(
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 782, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py", line 469, in api_request
    response = self._make_request(
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py", line 333, in _make_request
    return self._do_request(
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py", line 371, in _do_request
    return self.http.request(
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 476, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/credentials.py", line 302, in refresh
    ) = reauth.refresh_grant(
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/reauth.py", line 347, in refresh_grant
    _client._handle_error_response(response_data)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 60, in _handle_error_response
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_data)
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Token has been expired or revoked.'})
```

I have no issues whatsoever before this for months. My application bundle includes a `project-name-xxxx.json` file from Google Cloud Console. Everytime, I attempt to run the application it fails.

I have looked through some of the other answers that suggests tokens expire after 7 days for publishing mode `Testing`. The publishing mode is `Production` in our case.

Comment: The client authorization has been revoked. What type of authorization are you using - service account, CLI, compute metadata, etc? Try running this command first **gcloud auth application-default login**.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have a service account setup, that we're using for authentication.

Comment: Verify that the service account key has not been deleted/revoked/expired in the Google Cloud Console. Some keys (self-managed) can have an expiration date.

Comment: @JohnHanley They have not been deleted / revoked or expired. The expiration date is set to Dec 31, 9999 and both keys are active status.

Comment: Your question does not show the usage of a service account. That means you must be using credentials stored by the CLI and something is now messed up. Reinitialize the CLI: **gcloud init** and then assign the service account.

Comment: Hi OP, have you also tried explicitly authenticating your service account through your python code as shown in this documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file?